# Android XML putting object on maximum top (RelativeLayout)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I want to put some imageview and buttons on top of screen using relative layout. When I use `android:layout_alignParentTop = "true"`, it just does this:

[image]

instead of what I want to:

[image]

Any solutions how to implement this into RelativeLayout?

CODE: http://pastebin.com/NGcherYm
Due to long code I had to put in on pastebin.

Comment: post your layout xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove these lines

```
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```